# Why i cannot load with jquery an html under the current html file into a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load a specific html file and load it into the current page under a specific div.
I use the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#link").click(function(){
    $("#myDiv").load("load.html");
  });
});
</script>
```

and the link tag is like this:

```
 <li><span class="section"><a id="link" href="javascript:void(0);">Test</a></span></li>
```

But i am getting these errors:

```
OPTIONS file:///load.html No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. jquery.js:8706
send jquery.js:8706
x.extend.ajax jquery.js:8136
x.fn.load jquery.js:7745
(anonymous function) ec.html:71
x.event.dispatch jquery.js:5095
v.handle

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///load.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: is your source file on a different domain thanthe file to be loaded?

Comment: @gaurav5430 No.It's a simple html file under the same folder

Comment: are you using a web server?

Comment: @gaurav5430 no.should i?

Comment: Ok.I upload it on a webserver and it works

Answer (score 1):

try to add this header to your server config file

```
 <name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

EDIT:

if you're not using a local web server

> Due to security issues (same origin policy), javascript is not allowed
>   to access local files. Imagine a situation when javascript from a
>   website tries to steal your files. You have to deploy it to a web
>   server.

also see : [Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

EDIT: you may also wanna try

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
     url: "test.html", dataType: "html" 
}).done(function( responseHtml ) {
     $("#mydiv").html(responseHtml);
});
```

Note: `

> Because of same-origin policy, some browsers won't permit AJAX
>   requests to file:/// URLs, even if the original file was loaded that
>   way.

`